# Reading and Writing CSV files in a hadoop application

Tags: csv, hadoop, file-io, mapreduce

I need to process custom csv files as input and write csv files back to the HDFS. Can I do this directly inside the map reduce class where the real takes places?

For processing my csv files, I am using opencsv library. I have seen some tutorials where they use inputformat and outputformat flags to specify java classes which handle the user-defined formats. Can someone please give advice on how to work with csv files?

I want to stick with what hadoop has to offer, otherwise my own implementation of input and output formats may make my processing slow.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorials you are referencing?

Comment: http://blog.aggregateknowledge.com/2011/08/30/custom-inputoutput-formats-in-hadoop-streaming/, I must say that I could not find the exact one that I was mentioning, cleared my cache in the browser, could not find the exact the blog again. But something similar to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is if you need multi-line csv or not. 
 
If you do not need it - you can use vanilla TextInputFormat and TextOutputFormat and use opencsv inside you mapper to parse lines. For the output TextOutputFormat is also just fine 
If you need multiline - there are some hacks you have to do to assemble the logical records. You can create you own input format for it, or do it inside mapper.

Comment: what do you mean with multi-line csv? It is like field1,field2,field3;1,2,3;4,5,6; etc...

Comment: One CSV file is like a big matrix, with each element in it separated by comma or a particular specific character. Do you mean with multi-line this property?

Comment: In the CSV format, when fields are inside qoutation marks, we can have EOL symbols as part of the field content. It makes the single CSV record to span several lines,so you can not assume that one record = one line. OpenCSV has special option to process multiline csv.

Comment: in usual CSV , each line is one line of the matrix you mention. In multi-line - it is not the case.

Comment: got it. In my case, each line contains one particular record. Therefore, I can use the vanilla TextInputFormat and TextOutputFormat or even a String tokenized to read it line by line. Maybe I was thinking too complicated. Thanks!